# Python - how to check if a string is binary

Tags: python, string

feel this might be a naive question, but I was not able to find an answer. How to check if the `var` variable in following example is a binary string or regular string? I think `try: var.decode('ascii') except: ...` can do the job, but is there a better way?

```
var = b"abc"
```

Comment: Did you try `isinstance(var, str)` and/or `isinstance(var, bytes)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `isinstance()` built-in function for that.

The function takes 2 parameters. The first is the object you want to check and the second is the type you want to check against.

> isinstance(object, classinfo)
>
> Return True if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect, or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns False.

```py
var = b"abc"
if isinstance(var, bytes):
    # do something with binary string
elif isinstance(var, str):
    # do something with regular string
```